# A group of an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have this array of objects

```
[ { data: 50, note: 1 },
  { data: 0, note: 1 },
  { data: 0, note: 1 },
  { data: 25, note: 1 },
  { data: 0, note: 1 },
  { data: 40, note: 2 },
  { data: 40, note: 2 },
  { data: 20, note: 2 },
  { data: 0, note: 2 },
  { data: 0, note: 2 },
 ]
```

And I need to get this

```
{data:[
  {
   name: 1,
   data:[50,0,0,25,0]
  }
  {
   name: 2,
   data:[40,40,20,0,0]
  }
]}
```

I tried something like this, but I have not the result that I need

```
for(const {note} of data) {
   if(!result[note]) result[note] = [];
   result[note].push({ data });
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and group by `note`.

```js
var array = [{ data: 50, note: 1 }, { data: 0, note: 1 }, { data: 0, note: 1 }, { data: 25, note: 1 }, { data: 0, note: 1 }, { data: 40, note: 2 }, { data: 40, note: 2 }, { data: 20, note: 2 }, { data: 0, note: 2 }, { data: 0, note: 2 }],
    data = Array.from(
        array.reduce((m, { note, data }) => m.set(note, [...(m.get(note) || []), data]), new Map),
        ([name, data]) => ({ name, data })
    ),
    result = { data };

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is a great answer!

Answer (score 1):

There is short expression you can use

```
const a = ... //your array
const r = { data: [...new Set(a.map(x=>x.note))].map(x => { return { name:x, data: a.filter(y => y.note === x) } }) }
```

Comment: Nice, but please don't write that as a oneliner. Hard to read

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Map to collect the data into an array by `data`, and convert that to the final object structure with an `Array.from` mapping:

```js
const data = [ { data: 50, note: 1 },{ data: 0, note: 1 },{ data: 0, note: 1 },{ data: 25, note: 1 },{ data: 0, note: 1 }, { data: 40, note: 2 },{ data: 40, note: 2 },{ data: 20, note: 2 },{ data: 0, note: 2 },{ data: 0, note: 2 }];

const map = new Map(data.map(({note}) => [note, []]));
data.forEach(({note, data}) => map.get(note).push(data));
const result = Array.from(map, ([name, data]) => ({name, data}));

console.log(result);
```